# Enviar datos desde un programa c# a una plantilla T4 para generar un HTML

Tags: html, c#, visual-studio, report

Cree el formato de una factura con `HTML` y `css` y la tengo en una plantilla T4 pero necesito enviarle datos desde el programa principal, he utilizado la ayuda de Microsoft de la [pagina](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/modeling/run-time-text-generation-with-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2019)
en la parte de "pasar parametros en el constructor" pero no me esta funcionando.

En el archivo `templateFactura.tt` tengo esto en donde quiero meter la cadena "SOLICITUD DE PEDIDO"

```
<h1 style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  text-align:center">
  <#= m_data #> // aca debe decir "SOLICITUD DE PEDIDO"
 </h1>
```

Luego cree un archivo con una clase parcial llamado templateFacturaCode.Cs

```
public partial class templateFactura
{
private string m_data;

public templateFactura(string data) { this.m_data = data; }
}
```

Y en el programa principal tengo esto:

```
private void BtnGenerar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // StreamWriter sWrite = new StreamWriter("C://Users/mia/Desktop/htmlfile.html");
  //generar archivo deesde la plantilla t4
  string data = "SOLICITUD DE PEDIDO";
  templateFactura page = new templateFactura(data);
  String pageContent = page.TransformText();
  //System.IO.File.WriteAllText("C://Users/mia/Desktop/htmlfile.html", pageContent);

  //abre un archivo html y lo convierte en pdf
  //importar nuget Install-Package itext7.pdfhtml -Version 2.0.2

  //using (FileStream htmlSource = File.Open("C://Users/mia/Desktop/htmlfile.html", FileMode.Open))
  using (FileStream pdfDest = File.Open("C://Users/mia/Desktop/htmlfile.pdf", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
  {
     ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
     //HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(htmlSource, pdfDest, converterProperties);
     HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(pageContent, pdfDest, converterProperties);
  }

}
```

Aquí en el programa principal me devuelve el siguiente error:

> 'templateFactura' no contiene un constructor que tome 1 argumentos"
>   y en el archivo que se genera "templateFactura.cs" me marca que "el nombre 'm_data' no existe en el contexto actual

La verdad que mi nivel es muy bajo y ya me esta volviendo loca esto, si alguien me podría señalar el error, o pasarme alguna información me ayudaría muchísimo, saludos.

Comment: El generador de codigo no trabaja al mismo tiempo que el programa cuando se ejecuta, primero se genera el codigo y luego compila. Lo que puedes hacer es tener el Html y sustituir variables, como si fuera sustitucion de cadenas de  texto. Ejemplo <h1>{{titulo}}</h1>   creas una funcion que busque las variables del tipo {{Xvariable}}

Comment: gracias, quería evitar hacer eso pero parece que no va a quedar otra, saludos y gracias de nuevo por tu tiempo

Comment: Puedes dividirlo por secciones y sustituir directamente el valor de la variable interpolando el texto   var header= $" <h1> {titulo} <h1>" ; esto es mas parecido a que que quieres.

Comment: investigare eso, no me quedo claro tu segundo mensaje

Comment: Puedes utilizar sustitucion de texto var encabezadoTemplate="<div><b>Factura No [NumFactura]</b> <div>";   despues solo sustituyes en var encabezado=encabezadoTemplate.Replace("[NumFactura]","1233"); esto solo para pocas variables cuando son varias puedes usar string.Format ...

Comment: ahhh claro, deberia usar el strring.Format entonces ya que debo cargar varias tablas

Comment: He probado tu código en un proyecto que me he creado y funciona perfectamente, lo único que se me ocurre es que los espacios de nombres sean distintos y por eso no te coja la clase parcial que has generado. Si quieres puedo compartir el proyecto en GitHub

Comment: @JuanRu si, me faltaba agregar el espacio de nombres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues si solo quieres escribir tablas puede ser algo generico,
suponiendo que tus datos vienen de un DataTable

```
 public static string ConvertDataTableToHTML(DataTable dt)
    {
        string html = "<table>";
        //encabezados
        html += "<tr>";
        for(int i=0;i<dt.Columns.Count;i++)
            html+="<td>"+dt.Columns[i].ColumnName+"</td>";
        html += "</tr>";
        //renglones
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            html += "<tr>";
            for (int j = 0; j< dt.Columns.Count; j++)
                html += "<td>" + dt.Rows[i][j].ToString() + "</td>";
            html += "</tr>";
        }
        html += "</table>";
        return html;
    }
```

Comment: ah claro, y la variable "html" la usaría para reemplazar una cadena "@table" que meta en mi archivo html, verdad?

Comment: Si lo mejor es que reformules tu pregunta poniendo que es lo que esperas obtener e intentarlo, para que puedas crear un template o generador de template para las partes de tu reporte.

Comment: Segun parte de tu codigo primero generas el HTML y luego el pdf, es necesario el HTML ?, que libreria estas usando para conversion a pdf.

Comment: Así es, primero se generaría un HTML y luego se hace la conversión, estoy usando la librería iText 7 para convertir en pdf, y el HTML me lo han pedido porque quizá haya que darle otros usos.